# Dependent Multidrop down in Yii Framework

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, multi-select

I want to make two drop down

1. Select Group
2. Select Members (multi Drop Down)

When user select the first drop down (Group), i want to populate the Members Multidropdowen with the members of selected Group dynamically.

Select Members is a multidropdown and User can select more then One members.

I am able to accomplish dependent drop-down, or an independent Multidropdown, but i am not able to integrate these two.
I have tried the extensions `http://www.yiiframework[dot]com/extension/emultiselect` and `http://www.yiiframework[dot]com/extension/echmultiselect`.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cascadedropdown

Answer (score 0):

You to implement an ajax update for the first dropdown to update the 2nd one:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('country_id','', array(1=>'USA',2=>'France',3=>'Japan'),
array(
    'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST', //request type
    'url'=>CController::createUrl('currentController/dynamiccities'), //url to call.
    //Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
    'update'=>'#city_id', //selector to update
    //'data'=>'js:javascript statement' 
    //leave out the data key to pass all form values through
))); 
//empty since it will be filled by the other dropdown
echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_id','', array());
```

and in your controller you can have :

```
public function actionDynamiccities()
{
    $data=Location::model()->findAll('parent_id=:parent_id',
    array(':parent_id'=>(int) $_POST['country_id']));

    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
            array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
}
```

Source:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/